# Why is processPurchases() launuched two times in play-billing-samples?

Tags: android, google-play

Figure 3 and Code A is from the project play-billing-samples, you can see [here](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt).

From the document, `launchBillingFlow` may be triggered by a button click when the user wants to buy something, then `onPurchasesUpdated` will be launched.

I'm confused with the comment of `override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult){ }`, `onBillingSetupFinished` (include `processPurchases()`) will be launched when `BillingClient` has been successfully established.

Normally in a case, I need to init `BillingClient` first, `onBillingSetupFinished` be launched, `processPurchases()` will be launched too, then I click a *Buy* button, `onPurchasesUpdated` will be launched, and `processPurchases()` will be launched again.

Are there some problems with the code?

```
* Figure 3 -- Server-reliant billing integration with offline access to some entitlements
 *
 *  _____                        _________________
 * |Start|----------------------|launchBillingFlow|
 *  -----                        -----------------
 *                                        |
 *                                  ______v____________
 *                                 |onPurchasesUpdated |
 *                                  -------------------
 *                                 /      |
 *                   ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED   |
 *                               /        |
 *  _____       ________________v__       |
 * |Start|-----|queryPurchasesAsync|      OK
 *  -----       -------------------       |
 *                               \        |
 *                               v________v_______
 *                              |processPurchases |
 *                               -----------------
 *                                        |
 *   

                                 |
```

**Code A**

```
    /**
     * This is the callback for when the connection to the Play [BillingClient] has been successfully
     * established. It might make sense to get [SkuDetails] and [Purchases][Purchase] at this point.
     */
    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
        when (billingResult.responseCode) {
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished successfully")
                querySkuDetailsAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, GameSku.INAPP_SKUS)
                querySkuDetailsAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, GameSku.SUBS_SKUS)
                queryPurchasesAsync()
            }
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.BILLING_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                //Some apps may choose to make decisions based on this knowledge.
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, billingResult.debugMessage)
            }
            else -> {
                //do nothing. Someone else will connect it through retry policy.
                //May choose to send to server though
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, billingResult.debugMessage)
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onPurchasesUpdated(
            billingResult: BillingResult,
            purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?
    ) {
        when (billingResult.responseCode) {
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                // will handle server verification, consumables, and updating the local cache
                purchases?.apply { processPurchases(this.toSet()) }
            }
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED -> {
                // item already owned? call queryPurchasesAsync to verify and process all such items
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, billingResult.debugMessage)
                queryPurchasesAsync()
            }
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED -> {
                connectToPlayBillingService()
            }
            else -> {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, billingResult.debugMessage)
            }
        }
    }


   fun queryPurchasesAsync() {
       ...
       processPurchases(purchasesResult)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime it establishes a new connection to Google Play BillingClient before you click the "buy" button, `processPurchases` is called (from inside `queryPurchasesAsync()` to process any past purchases which have been purchased but not yet consumed. This may happen because of intermittent internet connection disruption or other reasons. You may treat this `processPurchases` call as to complete and consume previous purchases, if there is any.

Naturally, when you click the "buy" button, `processPurchases` is also invoked immediately. This may be the reason why you see two calls to `processPurchases` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't releasing the `billingClient` properly. So, if I exit the activity and open it again, it will cause this issue. The following code fixed my issue,

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (billingClient != null) {
            billingClient.endConnection();
            billingClient = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```